# Sum up in the transaction record

Tags: vb.net, string, text-files, readline

I have a Transaction data that need to sum up the amount, only sum up the amount with the date range.

`JJ|` is the Delimeter for every record and KD| is the transaction data.

Here is the data

```
JJ|        |
KD|15/08/16|        |CASH            |100.00|    |
KD|        |        |                |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|PACKAGE         |35.00 |AAAA|
KD|        |        |ONE             |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|PACKAGE         |35.00 |    |
KD|        |        |ONE             |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|PACKAGE         |35.00 |    |
KD|        |        |ONE             |      |    |
KD|        |        |                |      |    |
KD|15/08/16|        |CASH            |500.00|    |
KD|        |        |                |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|BREADER         |25.00 |BBBB|
KD|        |        |WWW             |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|BREADER         |25.00 |    |
KD|        |        |WWW             |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|BREADER         |25.00 |    |
KD|        |        |WWW             |      |    |
KD|        |        |                |      |    |
JJ|        |
KD|15/08/16|        |CASH            |110.00|    |
KD|        |        |                |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|ALIENWARE       |35.00 |CCCC|
KD|        |        |PPP             |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|ALIENWARE       |35.00 |    |
KD|        |        |PPP             |      |    |
KD|        |        |                |      |    |
KD|15/08/16|        |CREDIT          |210.00|    |
KD|        |        |                |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|PACKAGE         |25.00 |ABAB|
KD|        |        |ONE             |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|PACKAGE         |25.00 |    |
KD|        |        |ONE             |      |    |
KD|        |        |                |      |    |
```

Below is the code that need to tweak

```
Dim DelimeterAnnual 
While Not line Is Nothing
    Delimeter = line.Split("|")

    If Delimeter(0) = "JJ" Then
        fout.WriteLine(line)
    ElseIf Delimeter(0) = "KD" Then
        If Trim(Mid(Delimeter(2), 6, 3)) = "/17" Then
            If Trim(Delimeter(4)) = "" Then
            Else
                nAnnualBill += CDec(Delimeter(4))
                DelimeterAnnual = line.Split("|")
                fout.WriteLine(DelimeterAnnual(0) & "|" & DelimeterAnnual(1) & "|" & DelimeterAnnual(2) & "|" & DelimeterAnnual(3) _
                               & "|" & nAnnualBill & "|" & DelimeterAnnual(5))
            End If
        End If
    Else
        fout.WriteLine(line)
    End If

    line = fh.ReadLine
End While
```

Output I want to achieve:

```
JJ|        |
KD|15/08/16|        |CASH           |100.00|    |
KD|        |        |               |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|PACKAGE        |105.00|AAAA|
KD|        |        |ONE            |      |    |
KD|        |        |               |      |    |
KD|15/08/16|        |CASH           |500.00|    |
KD|        |        |               |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|BREADER        |75.00 |BBBB|
KD|        |        |WWW            |      |    |
KD|        |        |               |      |    |
JJ|        |
KD|15/08/16|        |CASH           |110.00|    |
KD|        |        |               |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|ALIENWARE      |70.00 |CCCC|
KD|        |        |PPP            |      |    |
KD|        |        |               |      |    |
KD|15/08/16|        |CASH           |210.00|    |
KD|        |        |               |      |    |
KD|01/09/16|30/09/17|PACKAGE        |50.00 |ABAB|
KD|        |        |ONE            |      |    |
KD|        |        |               |      |    |
```

Comment: What's with DelimeterAnnual = line.Split("|") again?

Comment: DelimeterAnnual = line.Split("|") 
to locate the amount and replace it with the amount sum up.

Comment: And you don't want to sum up CASH amounts, just the other lines for that transaction? Your issue here is you're outputting as soon as you process. Change your logic. Loop through it first, determine that this item is duplicate, if duplicate add to the amount. If cash, leave it alone. And then output that List to the format you want.